# Выровнять строки в колонках по базовой линии

Tags: html, css

В полиграфии есть такая фишка, можно выровнять текст в колонках таким образом, чтобы строки во всех колонках находились на одной линии. И даже если вставляешь картинки, текст не едет, а остается на этих линиях. Благодаря этому, много текста выглядит очень даже прилично.
Можно ли такое сделать средствами CSS?
Я делала поиски через подгонку line-height, но везде же так не подгонишь. У картинок разная высота.
Посоветуйте, товарищи, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данный момент приличного решения вашей проблемы нет.

Первый вариант ждать нормальной поддержки свойства [line-height-step](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height-step). Оно как раз решает вашу проблему.

Второй вариант задавать фиксированную высоту картинки и использовать свойства [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit), оно работает почти как `background-size`, только для `img`.

Comment: Дополню: размер картинки должен быть в em, с учетом параметра line-height.